# How to setup an Azure Search soft-delete policy attached to Azure Storage

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-cognitive-search, indexer

I have an `Azure Search` that uses `Azure Storage` as datasource. I'm trying to get the `Search` to delete files from it's result whenever they are deleted in the `Storage`, but somehow I can't seem to achieve it.

So far I've tried to setup a soft-delete policy on the `Storage` to keep files for another 7 days, and a soft-delete policy on the `Search` to check for the metadata column `IsDeleted` and if `true` delete the item from its results. Then using code I change the metadata and then delete the file as follows:

```
blob.Metadata["IsDeleted"] = "true";
blob.SetMetadataAsync().Wait();
blob.DeleteAsync().Wait();
```

Without the deleting it seems to work fine, but with it I guess the `Search` can no longer access the metadata even if the file is still retained. I'm assuming something as simply as this is already thought out, but I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is that you can't use soft delete blobs in Azure Search.

When a blob is soft deleted from storage, for all intents and purpose the blob is deleted. You can't perform any operation on the blob before undeleting it first. It is also not returned as part of regular blob listing process.

Because of this fact, when an indexer runs to fetch the list of blobs it does not find soft deleted blob. Only way to mark the blob deleted from search service indexer point of view is to keep the blob in storage and set the metadata property "IsDeleted" to "true" which you're doing.

Comment: Is there any other way to remove an item from the index, without rebuilding the entire index?

Comment: This is something you will need to do yourself. One possible way is to hook up Event Grid to trigger an event when a blob is deleted. In this event handler, you could programmatically delete a document from a search service index when a blob is deleted. You can find more about Event Grid and Blob Storage integration here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-event-overview. HTH.

Comment: I tried deleting it manually using `IndexBatch` which seems to work on the key value only. The key value is the `metadata_storage_path` and as is the default when creating an indexer through the portal I base64 encode it with `new FieldMapping("metadata_storage_path", "metadata_storage_path", new FieldMappingFunction("Base64Encode"))`. Manually encoding the URI yields a different result as the stored values which all seem to be equal with an extra character at the end, thus I can't seem to generate the key for deletion.

Comment: Can you share an example? Please share the actual URL of the blob, the value stored in search service and the value you manually computed.

Comment: Apparently `HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode` is used for encoding, where the last character is a `0`, `1` or `2` depending on the amount of `=` at the end of the base64 encoded string. As `=` is likely an invalid character to have in the key values for Azure Search this is a nice alternative. `HttpServerUtility` is `.NET Framework` though while my project is `.NET CORE`. I've yet to find an alternative that does the same. If not it's easy to solve myself now that I know what happens, although for readability I rather have a proper method.

Comment: It does a little more than that apparently but the code is found at [reference](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/Util/HttpEncoder.cs,0e3cb83cf51ca334) should anybody be interested in it